# definitions vs terminology

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Are these tags ([definitions](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions) vs [terminology](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)) should be the same, or one should be synonym over another? Or they have different purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tags are different. Let me explain with an example:

**definitions:** What is a deep neural network?

**Terminology:** Would this (< Insert some tech. behind some AI product/bot >) be a deep neural network or a RNN?

Comment: What about this [question](http://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1515/8), which one it is?

Comment: @kenorb It's asking about differences, so it's `definition`. If it talked about some algorithm, and asked to name/identify it, then it'd be `terminology` :)